# link between @Transactional and AOP

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I was reading some articles about `AOP` and I understand that it aims to increase modularity by allowing the separation of cross-cutting concerns and one of these concerns is the transaction which is simply manipulated by `@Transactional` with Spring.

So I want to ask what is the link between these two terms. And what exactly happens when I annotate a class by `@Transactional` ?

Answer (score 1):

For undestrand spring transaction managment you can read more information at the following link [Transaction Managment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)